# MacOS Photos on Mac mini does not import/see all photos from iPhones

Tags: macos, iphone, icloud, photos, photos.app

When I connect my iPhone SE to MacOS Photos, not all photos on the iPhone shows up for import.

In MacOS Photos import, it says:
Already Imported (483 items)
New Items (4 items)

and on the iPhone SE, it says:
1.220 Photos, 40 Videos

Setup: Mac mini (Late 2014, macOS Sierra 10.12.6 (16G1036)) with iCloud account and my wife's and mine iPhone SE (iOS 11.1.2), each with separate iCloud accounts. I want to import all photos from the iPhones to the Mac mini, back them up to iCloud and then delete them from the phones.

Comment: For the iPhone in question, have you checked if Photos on the Mac already downloaded the *missing* photos via iCloud?

Comment: Note that the 3 separate iCloud accounts, one for the Mac mini, one for my iPhone and one for my wife's iPhone. If I look at the photos on my iPhone, I can see photos, which is on the iPhone, but not on the mac Mini after import. I really do not understand what is going on?